# Show the series an/(1-an) converges given that series an converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that $0\le a_n\lt 1$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n)$ converges. Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges.

This question is supposed to be solved from first principles (e.g. Comparison Test); however, any approach would be appreciated.

I noted that $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n} = a_n + a_n^2 + a_n^3 + ...$ but I can't seem to finish the proof rigorously.

Comment: When you say "series $(a_n)$ converges", do you mean "the sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots$ converges" or do you mean "the series $\sum_i a_i$ converges"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a
finite number of the
$a_n$ such that
$a_n > \frac12$.

For all the others,
$\dfrac{a_n}{1-a_n}
\lt 2a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n\geq0$ and $\sum_na_n$ converges, $0\leq a_n<\frac12$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Then
$1-a_n\geq\frac12$ and so $0\leq\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}\leq 2 a_n$ for all sufficiently large $N$. The conclusion should be easy from here.
Incidentally, from your observation 
$$\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}=a_n+a^2_n+\ldots \geq a_n$$
It follows that if $a_n\geq0$, $\sum_na_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ converges.

Comment: Lovely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum a_n\text{ converges } \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{1}{1-a_n}=1$$

$$\implies \exists N : \forall n\ge N\;  0\le \frac{1}{1-a_n} \le 2$$

$$\implies \exists N : \forall n\ge N \; 0\le \frac{a_n}{1-a_n}<2a_n$$

nearly done.